# Missing Columns in Pandas DataFrame from CSV: How to Consolidate Data in a Single Row?

Tags: csv

I have a pandas DataFrame in Python containing CSV data, but only 10 out of the 14 columns are displayed when I load it. It appears that the missing columns' data are distributed across multiple rows, specifically rows 10, 11, 12, 13, and 14. I want to consolidate these columns into a single row using pandas.

**Details:**

I have a DataFrame representing CSV data containing a total of 14 columns. However, upon loading the data, I can only see 10 columns. The remaining columns (11, 12, 13, and 14) are spread across multiple rows (10, 11, 12, 13, and 14).

I want to combine the data from these columns into a single row to ensure the DataFrame has the correct structure. How can I merge the values from rows 10-14 into a new row and use it as the DataFrame's header row?

I've attempted various approaches to address this issue but have yet to succeed. Any guidance or code snippets would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is lacking tags (at least Python, but perhaps also the framework/modules you are using). Also, the code is missing.